# Python runs for 10 hours without errors or warnings. Is there any problem in my codes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I am running codes as follows. The main function of these codes is to create new columns based on known data and to fill the gap between months.
So in the function, firstly I fill the gap in months and then calculate new variables.
I need to update two dataframes, each has about 80 columns and millions of rows.

I run these codes for more than 10 hours, without any errors or warnings. Python is still running now, but I am not sure if there are any mistakes in my codes so that it takes so long.

My desktop has 64G RAM and 64-core processor.
[Current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG4Po.png)

```
def expand_dates(ser):
    return pd.DataFrame({'datadate': pd.date_range(ser['datadate'].min(), ser['datadate'].max(), freq='M')})

def add_helper_vars(x):
    y=x.groupby(['gvkey', 'curcd']).apply(expand_dates).reset_index().merge(x,how='left',on=['gvkey', 'curcd','datadate']).ffill()
    y['data_available']=y['gvkey'].notnull()
    y=y.drop_duplicates(['gvkey', 'curcd','datadate'],keep='first')
    y['count']=y.sort_values(by=['gvkey', 'curcd','datadate']).groupby(['gvkey', 'curcd'])['datadate'].rank(method='first')
    
    var_pos=['at', 'sale', 'revt', 'dv', 'che']
    for a in var_pos:
        y.loc[y[a]<0,a]=np.nan
    
    y['sale_x']=y['sale'].combine_first(y['revt'])
    y['gp_x']=y['gp'].combine_first(y['sale_x']-y['cogs'])
    y['opex_x']=y['xopr'].combine_first(y['cogs']+y['xsga'])
    y['ebitda_x']=y['ebitda'].combine_first(y['oibdp']).combine_first(y['sale_x']-y['opex_x']).combine_first(y['gp_x']-y['xsga'])
    y['ebit_x']=y['ebit'].combine_first(y['oiadp']).combine_first(y['ebitda_x']-y['dp'])
    y['op_x']=y['ebitda_x']+y['xrd'].fillna(0)
    y['ope_x']=y['ebitda_x']-y['xint']
    y['pi_x']=y['pi'].combine_first(y['ebit_x']-y['xint']+y['spi'].fillna(0)+y['nopi'].fillna(0))
    y['xido_x']=y['xido'].combine_first(y['xi']+y['do'].fillna(0))
    y['ni_x']=y['ib'].combine_first(y['ni']-y['xido_x']).combine_first(y['pi_x']-y['txt']-y['mii'].fillna(0))
    y['nix_x']=y['ni'].combine_first(y['ni_x']+y['xido_x'].fillna(0)).combine_first(y['ni_x']+y['xi']+y['do'])
    y['fi_x']=y['nix_x']+y['xint']
    y['div_x']=y['dvt'].combine_first(y['dv'])
    
    y['eqbb_x']=sum(y['prstkc'],y['purtshr'])
    y['eqis_x']=y['sstk']
    y['eqnetis_x']=sum(y['eqis_x'],-y['eqbb_x'])
    y['eqpo_x']=y['div_x']+y['eqbb_x']
    y['eqnpo_x']=y['div_x']-y['eqnetis_x']
    y['dltnetis_x']=sum(y['dltis'],-y['dltr']).combine_first(y['ltdch']).combine_first(y['dltt']-y['dltt'].shift(12))
    y.loc[y['dltis'].isnull() & y['dltr'].isnull()& y['ltdch'].isnull() &(y['count']<=12),'dltnetis_x'] =np.nan
    y['dstnetis_x']=y['dlcch'].combine_first(y['dlc']-y['dlc'].shift(12))
    y.loc[y['dlcch'].isnull() &(y['count']<=12),'dstnetis_x'] =np.nan
    y['dbnetis_x']=sum(y['dstnetis_x'],y['dltnetis_x'])
    y['netis_x']=y['eqnetis_x']+y['dbnetis_x']
    y['fincf_x']=y['fincf'].combine_first(y['netis_x']-y['dv']+y['fiao'].fillna(0)+y['txbcof'].fillna(0))
    
    y['debt_x']=sum(y['dltt'],y['dlc'])
    y['pstk_x']=y['pstkrv'].combine_first(y['pstkl']).combine_first(y['pstk'])
    y['seq_x']=y['seq'].combine_first(y['ceq']+y['pstk_x'].fillna(0)).combine_first(y['at']-y['lt'])
    y['at_x']=y['at'].combine_first(y['seq_x']+y['dltt']+y['lct'].fillna(0)+y['lo'].fillna(0)+y['txditc'].fillna(0))
    y['ca_x']=y['act'].combine_first(y['rect']+y['invt']+y['che']+y['aco'])
    y['nca_x']=y['at_x']-y['ca_x']
    y['cl_x']=y['lct'].combine_first(y['ap']+y['dlc']+y['txp']+y['lco'])
    y['ncl_x']=y['lt']-y['cl_x']
    
    y['netdebt_x']=y['debt_x']-y['che'].fillna(0)
    y['txditc_x']=y['txditc'].combine_first(sum(y['txdb'],y['itcb']))
    y['be_x']=y['seq_x']+y['txditc_x'].fillna(0)-y['pstk_x'].fillna(0)
    y['bev_x']=(y['icapt']+y['dlc'].fillna(0)-y['che'].fillna(0)).combine_first(y['netdebt_x']+y['seq_x']+y['mib'].fillna(0))
    
    y['coa_x']=y['ca_x']-y['che']
    y['col_x']=y['cl_x']-y['dlc'].fillna(0)
    y['cowc_x']=y['coa_x']-y['col_x']
    y['ncoa_x']=y['at_x']-y['ca_x']-y['ivao'].fillna(0)
    y['ncol_x']=y['lt']-y['cl_x']-y['dltt']
    y['nncoa_x']=y['ncoa_x']-y['ncol_x']
    y['fna_x']=y['ivst'].fillna(0)+y['ivao'].fillna(0)
    y['fnl_x']=y['debt_x']+y['pstk_x'].fillna(0)
    y['nfna_x']=y['fna_x']-y['fnl_x']
    y['oa_x']=y['coa_x']+y['ncoa_x']
    y['ol_x']=y['col_x']+y['ncol_x']
    y['noa_x']=y['oa_x']-y['ol_x']
    y['lnoa_x']=y['ppent']+y['intan']+y['ao']-y['lo']+y['dp']
    
    y['caliq_x']=y['ca_x-invt'].combine_first(y['che']+y['rect'])
    y['nwc_x']=y['ca_x']-y['cl_x']
    y['ppeinv_x']=y['ppegt']+y['invt']
    y['aliq_x']=y['che']+0.75*y['coa_x']+0.5*(y['at_x']-y['ca_x']-y['intan'].fillna(0))
    
    var_bs= ['be_x', 'bev_x']
    for a in var_bs:
        y.loc[y[a]<=0,a]=np.nan
    
    y['caliq_x']=(y['ni_x']-y['oancf']).combine_first(y['cowc_x']-y['cowc_x'].shift(12)+y['nncoa_x']-y['nncoa_x'].shift(12))
    y['tacc_x']=y['oacc_x']+y['nfna_x']-y['nfna_x'].shift(12)
    y.loc[y['count']<=12,'caliq_x'] =np.nan
    y.loc[y['count']<=12,'tacc_x'] =np.nan
    y['ocf_x']=y['oancf'].combine_first(y['ni_x']-y['oacc_x']).combine_first(y['ni_x']+y['dp']-y['wcapt'].fillna(0))
    y['fcf_x']=y['ocf_x']-y['capx']
    y['cop_x']=y['ebitda_x']+y['xrd'].fillna(0)-y['oacc_x']
    
    y=y.drop('count',1)
    return y

acc_std_ann=add_helper_vars(compa2)
acc_std_qtr=add_helper_vars(compq6)
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? Wait until it finishes. If there's a problem, Python will tell you.

Comment: You should add some print statements to find the bottleneck(s)

Comment: I assume you tested the code first with smaller dataframes to ensure everything runs okay, right?

Comment: I have no clear expectations for how long it will take. In the previous steps with similar dataframes, it took less than 20 minutes.